# IBM.XMS ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2035

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, xms

I am trying to send Text messages using IBM XMS for .NET. I am getting following error at the time of calling CreateConnection method of IConnectionFactory

> Additional information: CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during
>   the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode:
>   2, Reason: 2035.

As per http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041060_.htm?lang=en, user is not authorized. I am new to IBM MQ, How do I authorize the user ?

Comment: What version of MQ are you using?

Comment: I am using IBM MQ v8.0

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a MQRC of 2035 is encountered, the correct thing to do is to look in the `AMQERR01.LOG` on the queue manager machine to see the exact reason why you were not authorized. If you don't then know what to do upon reading the error message you see there, please include the full error message in your question.